# Is it possible to use a portable library with localized resources in a Universal app?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

(There's a link at the bottom to a solution with repro of the problem.)

I've been using a portable library with .resx resources for quite some time as it worked for both Windows Store apps and Windows Phone apps. I tried to use it with a Universal app as well, and it works for the Windows Store part, but does not work for Windows Phone.

The problem occurs only when I try to deploy the app on a device (built with the Release configuration). If I just Build it, it does not give an error (but it still can't be deployed on the device successfully). I get the following error:

```
Error : DEP6810 : MdilXapCompile.exe failed with error code 1004. See log file
'...\Phone App Test\Phone App Test\obj\Release\MDIL\MDILXapCompileLog.txt' for more details.
```

And in that file:

```
Error: Compile filter argument specified non-existent file:
...\Phone App Test\Phone App Test\obj\Release\MSIL\en-US\PCL.resources.dll
Invalid argument
```

The file truly isn't there, but the app does not support the en-US culture anyway, only the library does, so I don't think this file should be needed.

Any idea how I can resolve this issue?

Here's a simple solution with the problem: [link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=A6C2D3754FAFFD50!19210&authkey=!AJ7wMa8jUu9eMyQ&ithint=file%2czip)

Comment: Have you found solution for this problem?

Comment: @MartinSuchan Not a real solution, only a workaround (although not fully tested yet, but it seems to work). I just manually copied the assemblies it's expecting. We'll be releasing the app this week, so after the final tests I'll post this as answer if everything's is okay. There might be a better solution, but I couldn't find it in the time I had for resolving it.

Comment: Well for us this also happens with Visual Studio 2015. Magically it works well with Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have .resx files in pcls, you just have to use the workaround explained on http://blogs.msdn.com/b/philliphoff/archive/2014/11/19/missingmanifestresourceexception-when-using-portable-class-libraries-in-winrt.aspx

Even with the latest VS 2013 (update 5) the mdil error will appear when trying to deploy Release packages.

> MdilXapCompile.exe failed with error code 1004

To work around it you must compile your app using the store option and then use the Application Deployment tool to actually deploy it to the device.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the workaround described on [Phil Hoff blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/philliphoff/archive/2014/11/19/missingmanifestresourceexception-when-using-portable-class-libraries-in-winrt.aspx) did not work for me too well. I have developed my own workaround. It turns out if you are using .resx files to store string values only, then you can easily convert them to .resw and use natively in Windows Phone 8.1.

So what I am doing is copying and converting resources from PCL and placing as native .resw resources in Windows Phone project every build automatically using the tool I made - [ResxHell](https://github.com/konradbartecki/ResxHell). Just follow the instructions on the repository and you can then reach resources like this

```
var resourceLoader = new ResourceLoader();
var localizedText = resourceLoader.GetString("MyCustomReswFile/MyStringId");
```

For nice binding I ended up creating ValueConventer and small localization helper class, take a look at this gist: [Binding from .resw files example](https://gist.github.com/konradbartecki/3e315c3b24f5eb1dd413)

With the use of that you can do following in your xaml pages:

```
//For resource in file Page.Login.resw and string ID "NotUserYet"
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ConverterParameter=Page.Login/NotUserYet, Converter={StaticResource ResString}, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource ResString}}"/>
```

or
`string localizedtext = LocalizationHelper.GetString("MyCustomReswFile", "MyStringId");`

Comment: You should make the tool generate a cs file like the one that comes with resx resources. :P Doing anything by strings is uncool.

Comment: @Yasen Yeah I thought about that too, but that approach could be a bit more difficult and I don't really have enough time to do this :P. I am right now figuring out how to access string resources in a more elegant way. Once I'll find out I will let you know :-)

Answer (score 1):

I found this is already reported to ms connect

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/991028/issue-using-resx-files-on-winrt-apps-windows-phone-and-windows

and there is a workaround I haven't tried yet.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/philliphoff/archive/2014/11/19/missingmanifestresourceexception-when-using-portable-class-libraries-in-winrt.aspx

Unfortunatelly it has not been fixed so far.

Comment: Also unfortunately it is marked as "Fixed" in the mentioned issue without any further explanation, while not working in VS 2013 update 4 - let's hope it's fixed in the upcoming Visual Studio edition ...

Answer (score 0):

You certainly unchecked the "Build" checkbox in the Configuration Manager, that's why the resources are not copied automatically. Check it and it will works.

Comment: Thanks @Poppyto for the suggestion, but no - that was not the problem. I still don't know why they were needed in the first place, nor why they weren't copied. Anyway, even when I copied them manually, the app wasn't working in Release for some reason, so I switched to .resw resources and a Universal Class Library.

Comment: You are alright, I finally also switched to resw (in fact I just rename resx on an MSBUILD task to temp resw, So i could use my resx in my WP7/8 project)

Comment: @Poppyto could you explain how did you rename the files on MSBuild task, please?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, it seems you can't use PCL library with localized resources using .resx files in the WP part of a Universal app. At least it's not trivial.

There were runtime problems when the app is build in Realese configuration, which I couldn't resolve, so I decided to change to .resw resources. This solved my problems, of course, but I had to duplicate the resources, which is what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: But it's impossible! How to use it in the other PCL library? I'm sad

Comment: This information is not accurate you can build and deploy the app, please uncheck your answer as the correct one.

Comment: @DVD Sure thing :) It's good that there's some workaround now for those who need it and can't just switch to .resw files.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. I tried deploying via Windows Phone Deployment Tool and it worked.
So instead of using Visual Studio to deploy: create packages and put them on phone and it works!!

Comment: Did you build in Release? Also, have you tried building a package for the store and deploying it? I didn't have problems building in Debug and in some other scenarios, but couldn't build a working release version for the Store (if I remember correctly... that was some time ago.) (I'm asking so that we know if it's truly fixed, not that I particularly need it. :))