# MdilXapCompile error 1004 when deploying to device in Release mode

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, portable-class-library

I'm building a Windows Phone 8.1 application. For localization resources used in it's views, it uses the 'new' `.resw` files.

For several reasons I've built the application's view models in a portable class library. These view models also use some localizable texts which I've placed in `.resx` files inside the same project. Initially, everything seemed to be working well.

Today, I noticed that I'm unable to deploy my application to a physical device in **Release** mode and I've determined that the resx-files are somehow causing this. Visual Studio gives me this error when I try to deploy:

> DEP6810 : MdilXapCompile.exe failed with error code 1004. See log file
>   'C:\MySolution\MyPCLProject\obj\Release\MDIL\MDILXapCompileLog.txt'
>   for more details.

In the log file itself:

> Error: Compile filter argument specified non-existent file:
>   C:\MySolution\MyPCLProject\obj\Release\MSIL\en\MyPCLProject.resources.dll
>   Invalid argument
>
> Microsoft (R) MDIL XAP Compiler - Version 4.0.0.0 Copyright (c)
>   Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Usage: MDILXAPCompile /In: /Out:
>   /Config: [/CompileFilter:;]
>   [/Timeout:] [/Log:] [/AppX]

What does work?

- *Compiling* in Debug and Release builds
- Deploying to the WP emulator in Debug and Release builds
- Running deployed software

It seems like a very weird limitation to me, but so far I've been unable to determine why just this one (unfortunately rather important) case fails.

**Does anyone know if I can make the resources work like they already are in a Debug build?**

I've created a [blank solution](http://thorarin.net/external/stackoverflow/WP81-PCL-resx.zip) (.zip 41 kB) that should reproduce the error. The application displays the only resource in the PCL in a TextBlock to confirm the resource has been embedded.

Comment: Have exact same issue. Works nicely for WinRT (8.1 x64) and Android (Xamarin.Forms), but recently deploying to WP 8.1 gives these issues.
I'm using Windows App Localization Toolkit.

Comment: Microsoft.Data.Edb, Microsoft.OData and System.Spatial - same error.

Answer (score 1):

I have ran into similar problem when trying to deploy physical device whether it was set to Debug or Release.
One of the workarounds is to follow the instructions on [Phil Hoff's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/philliphoff/archive/2014/11/19/missingmanifestresourceexception-when-using-portable-class-libraries-in-winrt.aspx) but that didn't really work for me so I invented my own workaround.

It turns out .resx files can be easily converted to .resw (native Windows Phone 8.1 resource format) if these contain string values only.
I have developed a [small tool](https://github.com/konradbartecki/ResxHell) which copies .resx from PCL and places them in Windows Phone 8.1 project as .resw files every build automatically. Then you can reach them from code like this:

```
var resourceLoader = new ResourceLoader();
var localizedText = resourceLoader.GetString("MyCustomReswFile/MyStringId");
```

Also take a look at this question

[Unable to access localized resources in .NET 4.5 PCL from Windows Phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33262347/unable-to-access-localized-resources-in-net-4-5-pcl-from-windows-phone-8-1/33305527#33305527)

For nice binding I ended up creating ValueConventer and small localization helper class, take a look at this gist: [Binding from .resw files example](https://gist.github.com/konradbartecki/3e315c3b24f5eb1dd413)

With the use of that you can do following in your xaml pages:

```
//For resource in file Page.Login.resw and string ID "NotUserYet"
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ConverterParameter=Page.Login/NotUserYet, Converter={StaticResource ResString}, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource ResString}}"/>
```

or
`string localizedtext = LocalizationHelper.GetString("MyCustomReswFile", "MyStringId");`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's related to an issue with localization in a PCL when deploying to WP81, which is unsolved.

Read more:

[Is it possible to use a portable library with localized resources in a Universal app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26238570/is-it-possible-to-use-a-portable-library-with-localized-resources-in-a-universal)